# Sum int values in unsorted ArrayList based on dates

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got a list of objects with LocalDateTime and int fields.
Here is an example of an object from the list:

```
   new CustomObject(LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 01, 06, 0), 20)
```

How to check whether a sum of ints on a certain date (multiple entries for the same date possible) does not exceed some value for O(n) or better? forEach loop must be used, sorting is restricted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.date.toLocalDate(), Collectors.summingInt(o -> o.value))).values().anyMatch(sum -> sum > max)`

Comment: Build a `Map<LocalDate, Integer>` with the sums, then stop if a sum exceeds the limit.

Comment: @shmosel Question says *"forEach loop must be used"*, so Stream solution is not valid.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to put more effort into your question. You have not shown what you have tried nor what other restrictions apply. I suggest you rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this task by writing a comparator for dates and sorting the incoming list. However, this was O(n^2) and thus unacceptable. I struggled with defining proper `(K, V)` for a map and @Andreas gave me a clue.

There is not much to be added to his answer - I filled the map and summed ints for each LocalDate in a map.